# How to rollback a WAR deployment build to a earlier successful tomcat deployment in Jenkins, while using Deploy war/ear to a container

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, deployment

I have created a Job in Jenkins where in I have added a "**Post-build**" action using "***Deploy war/ear to a container***" to deploy WAR to a running Tomcat. The job is working fine.

The job fails when there is error in deployment on tomcat due to some reasons (like ***unknown JNDI*** in context.xml).

I want to know if there is any way to rollback the deployment to the previous build that was in tomcat in case deployment from my Job fails.

Comment: You might consider using the "War Replacement" solution proposed by Tomcat. If you do that I suppose the server will rollback the replacement if the new war didn't deploy correctly.

Comment: @Zorglube Can you please elaborate a bit on "War Replacement", or point me to some links. As far as I know. When you replace a war in webapps folder of tomcat, tomcat deploys. But how can it rollback if the WAR file is overwritten?

Comment: I'm not sure but, you'll find something in this https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat, you can just deploy a war file with a different name, for example a different major version. So, inside your webapps folder, you have two war files:

- process-1.war
- process-2.war

... and corresponding directories (at least, if you've set unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" in server.xml):

- process-1
- process-2

Both versions are usable at this point. The standard application url will default to process_2.

If you remove process_2 war file and directory, or - equivalently - press "undeploy" in the tomcat admin console, the old version will be default again, which means you've rolled back to the older version.